# What is a ".pxi.in" file and how to use it?

Tags: pandas, cython

I need to understand the source code of pandas. I met several ".pxi.in" files in the source code. For example:
https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi.in
The files say

> DO NOT edit .pxi FILE directly, .pxi is generated from .pxi.in

I want to know how to use .pxi.in files to generate .pxi files. Is there any tutorials or docs?

Answer (score 3):

Cython comes with [tempita](https://pyrocore.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tempita.html). The idea behind it is more or less to have a kind of preprocessor-language for Cython, because otherwise Cython is somewhat lacking this functionality compared to C or C++-templates.

`*.pxi.in` from pandas uses tempita, to create e.g. classes for `int8`, `int16` usw. from a template, so one doesn't have to repeat the code per hand. `*.pxi.in` files are converted to `*.pxi`-file in the [setup.py-file](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/setup.py#L79-L97).

As example

```
{{py:

# name
complex_types = ['complex64',
                 'complex128']
}}

{{for name in complex_types}}
cdef kh{{name}}_t to_kh{{name}}_t({{name}}_t val) nogil:
    cdef kh{{name}}_t res
    res.real = val.real
    res.imag = val.imag
    return res

{{endfor}}
```

will be converted, once tempita step was performed, to

```
cdef khcomplex64_t to_khcomplex64_t(complex64_t val) nogil:
    cdef khcomplex64_t res
    res.real = val.real
    res.imag = val.imag
    return res

cdef khcomplex128_t to_khcomplex128_t(complex128_t val) nogil:
    cdef khcomplex128_t res
    res.real = val.real
    res.imag = val.imag
    return res
```

and the resulting pxi-file will be used while cythonizing pyx-files.

Comment: It's probably worth adding: right now Tempita is mostly for Cython's internal use, and so largely undocumented. Scipy and Pandas have just decided to use it because it's useful to them, and convenient. That may change in future (probably to make Tempita more of a supported public feature). But it isn't a routine part of writing Cython code